# DynamoDB FilterExpression with multiple condition python and boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

Please I need help writing filter expressions for scanning data in dynamo db tables using python and boto3.

See my code below.

For some reason unknown to me, this search filter below which I am using is not giving me the right results

Please advice

```
dynamo_db = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

table = dynamo_db.Table(TABLE_NAME)

my_kwargs = {
    'FilterExpression': Key('column_1').eq(val_type_1) and Key("column_2").eq("val_type_string")
}
response = table.scan(**my_kwargs)

items = response['Items']
table_item = items[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use Scan you do not filter on `Key`. You filter here is in an attribute so you will need to change `Key` to `Attr`.

Furthermore you will need to implement pagination if you are scanning more than 1Mb of data:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html